# Maximum principle of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

> > Show: If $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function on a domain $G$, then $\lvert f\rvert$ has no local maximum on $G$. **Hint**: Use the mean value property of holomorphic functions!

Suppose that $\lvert f\rvert$ has a local maximum in $z_0\in G$. Then it exists a $r>0$ so that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq\lvert f(z_0)\rvert~\forall~z\in B(r,z_0)$. (*)

The mean value property says
$$
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{it})\, dt,
$$
so it is, because of (*),
$$
\lvert f(z_0)\rvert\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z_0+re^{it})\rvert\, dt\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z_0)\rvert\, dt=\lvert f(z_0)\rvert
$$
and therefore
$$
\lvert f(z_0)\rvert=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z_0+re^{it})\rvert\, dt.
$$

Can I now use that result to get a contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $t\mapsto |f(z_0)|-|f(z_0+re^{it})|$ is non-negative, continuous, and its integral over $[0,2\pi]$ is $0$, hence for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$, we have that $|f(z_0+re^{it})|=|f(z_0)|$. It's true for $r$ small enough, hence the modulus of $f$ is constant on a ball centered on $z_0$. Using Cauchy-Riemann equations, it can be shown that $f$ is actually constant on the ball, and by connectedness on the domain.

Comment: Why is $\lvert f(z_0+re^{it})\rvert = \lvert f(z_0)\rvert$ for all $t\in [0,2\pi]$? -- Is this a proof using my results or a different proof?

Comment: It's actually a calculus result (for functions with real values): if a continuous non-negative function has a $0$ integral, it is actually the null function.

Comment: Hm, okay. Thank you for answering. Neverhtless I would like to know if one can continue my proof.

Comment: Isn't it the continuation of your proof?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Of course. I had a wrong thought. So if I understood you correct: $\lvert f(z_0)\rvert=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\lvert f(z_0+re^{it})\rvert\, dt\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(\lvert f(z_0+re^{it})\rvert-\lvert f(z_0)\rvert)\ dt=0\Leftrightarrow\lvert f(z_0+re^{it})\rvert=\lvert f(z_0)\rvert$ Did I understand you right to this point of your answer? And what do you mean with "modulus of $f$" - I dont know that word.

Comment: Modulus of $f$ is $|f|$. Yes, that the idea.

Comment: One more question: I've heard that to show that f is locally constant one does not have to use Cauchy-Riemann (which I have used now). Another possibility is using suitable logarithm? Would be interesteding to know that way, too.