# Show that for every $r > 0$ there exist a $w$ $\in$ $D(0,r)$ that satisfies $\lvert h(w) \rvert > 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, maximum-principle

I'm learning about *Complex Analysis* and need some help with this problem:

> Consider the function $h(z) = (1 - \frac z5 - \frac{z^3}{10})e^{iz}$.
>   Show that for every $r > 0$ there exist a $w$ $\in$ $D(0,r)$ that
>   satisfies $\lvert h(w) \rvert > 1$.

I'm assuming the $D(0,r)$ is the disk of radius $r$ centered at zero. I think I should use the *Maximum Modulus Principle* but I don't know how to apply it here. I'm also looking for solutions using other methods/theorems (if possible).

Comment: " In other words : ∣h(w)∣>1∀w∈ℂ∖{0}. Is this right?" No, for each $r>0$ there is *some* $w$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maximum Modulus Principle as applied to this problem says:  If $z_0 \in D(0,r)$ and $|f(z)| \le |f(z_0)|$ for all $z \in D(z_0,R)$, with $R > 0$ such that $D(z_0, R) \subseteq D(0,r)$, then $f$ is constant on $D(0,r)$.

To use it, first suppose for the sake of contradiction that there is **no** $w$ such that $|h(w)| > 1$ for **any** $r > 0$.  In other words, you have $|h(w)| \le 1$ for all $r > 0$.  So, no matter what $r > 0$ is, you have $|h(w)| \le 1$.

We also know that no matter what $r > 0$ is, we have $0 \in D(0,r)$.  Also, we know that $|h(0)| = 1$.  So for any $r > 0$ we can say the following:

$0 \in D(0,r)$ and $|h(w)| \le |h(0)|$ for all $w \in D(0,r)$ (and therefore for all $w \in D(0,R)$ for any $R > 0$ such that $D(0,R) \subseteq D(0,r)$).

So by the Maximum Modulus Principle stated above (using $0$ for $z_0$ and using $h$ instead of $f$), we see that $h$ is constant on $D(0,r)$.  But this is clearly a contradiction because the provided function $h$ is certainly not constant on any $D(0,r)$.  Therefore it must be the case that for every $r > 0$, there is a $w \in D(0,r)$ such that $|h(w)| > 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. It was extremely helpful and understandable.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

What is $h(0)$? Now what does a certain big theorem tell you? It's a really big theorem. Bigger than the other theorems. Sort of a maximal theorem...

Comment: If I distribute I get $h(0) = 1$. Are you referring to the fundamental theorem of algebra? "Every polynomial equation of degree n with complex coefficients has n roots in the complex numbers." I don't see how this theorem will help me prove the first statement.

Comment: You'll have to find someone else on this one.

Comment: Despite my doubts about the aphoristic nature of this answer, it is correct.

Comment: Weird weird hint. At first I thought of Picard's theorem.

Comment: @zhw. It's a pun. Maximal...

Answer (score 1):

Since you want something more complete than David Ullrich's good hint, assume the contrary, i.e. that $|h(w)| \le 1$ for all $w$ with $|w| = r$. Then the maximum modulus principle implies that $|h(w)| \le 1$ for all $w$ with $|w| \le r$.

Next note that $h(0) = 1$, which shows that $|h|$ must have a local maximum at $z=0$, which [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480563/maximum-principle-of-holomorphic-functions) that $h$ is constant on $|w| \le r$, but this is clearly a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $x \in \mathbb {R},$ let $f(x) = 1 +x/5 -x^3/10.$ Note $f'(0)> 0,$ hence $f(x) > 1$ in some interval $(0,\delta), \delta > 0.$